# Marketing Cloud CloudPage Error 403 - Forbidden Access?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, landing-page

Some recipients are receiving error 403 forbidden access when accessing the cloud page, any thoughts? Worked fine during the testing for all parties?

Comment: Is anything changed on the roles? Also try a different browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd need to see the code that you are using to generate the link to the CloudPage, but this error typically occurs when you are trying to access the base domain. For example:

`https://cloud.subdomain.example.com/`

Instead of:

`https://cloud.subdomain.example.com/pageName`

This is the only scenario that I'm aware of that would return a 403 HTTP Status Code. I'd ask your affected Subscribers to supply the actual URL of the CloudPage that they are viewing to validate this.